# SQL Query Result to Body of Email (with columns) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, email

I am a novice python user and I am trying to create a program that:

1. Run a SQL query and attach the result to an email (I have
   accomplished this, shown below)
2. Run another shorter SQL query to summarize the attachment and paste
   the result in the body of the email (with columns, so it’s easier to
   read)

***Questions:***

1. I am stuck on the #2. Any guidance is appreciated
2. for the #1, my code runs fine and I receive the email with
   attachment but some how after 30 min I get an email from Database
   admin that my query has been running for 30 minutes. Not sure what I
   am doing that is causing the query to run in the back?

If you see any other issues with my code, please let me know. Thank you

```
import csv
import datetime
import shutil
import smtplib
import pyodbc

import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql
import win32com.client as win32

server = 'WESTBIS'
db1 = 'ExternalUser' 
db2 = 'BI_MIP'
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=WESTBIS;'
                      'Database1=ExternalUser;'
                      'Database2=BI_MIP;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("My sql query") 
col_headers = [ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]
rows = [ list(i) for i in cursor.fetchall()]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=col_headers)
df.to_csv("----.csv", header = True, index=False)
newPath = shutil.copy('--------.csv', 'C:/Users/Documents/----/')
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = '12345@email.com'
mail.Subject = 'EMAIL SUBJECT'
mail.Body = 'EMAIL BODY'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>BODY OF EMAIL IN HTML</h2>' 
attachment = "C:\\Users\\-----\\Documents\\Projects\\------.csv"
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

mail.Send()
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert the Data Frame to html? The function is to_html

Comment: Try: `mail.HTMLBody = df.to_html()`